# What is the best way to debug rocke-chip chisel code?

Tags: debugging, chisel, rocket-chip

My question is about how to actually understand and modify rocket-chip code. Reading the documentation, it seems to me that running the emulator with `+verbose` flag to enable `prinf` is the recommended way. I am not sure about the effectiveness of that, because the time to generate the emulator is too long (about 20 minutos in my PC). There is another way?

PS: I try to import and run the project in Intellij IDE to use the internal debugger, but I fail on that.

PS2: My PC setting:
Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 8
8GB RAM
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS